# How to print inner most taxonomy of a taxonomy hierarchy in a Wordpress loop?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this kind of custom taxonomy hierarchy in my custom post type  
[image]
 
How do I print dynamically (in a loop) the most inner term/ taxonomy?  In this case I want to print Lavakaaret in my Loop. I tried `the_taxonomies()`but this prints all off them.
And I think my way of using these terms for the Wordpress categories ("Taxonomies", "terms", etc...) is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out a function for this.`wp_get_post_terms()`
Further more, using `end($array)` will select the last item in that array.
Example:

```
    $terms =wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,'tuotteet');
    echo 'Katagorie: '.end($terms)->name;
```